# CSS-Grid columns do not align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, materialize

Basically, I often run into this kind of issue, that the columns of my grid do not align as intended. ([Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/), and others) Everytime the same issue, sometimes I get it fixed, other times I struggle for hours trying to get it work.

That's really annyoing and I really wan't to know why this issue happens and how to solve it in future projects!

The problems is the following:

I have a layout example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/)), which I want to sovle. It's using [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) with some sections.

```
  Large View (with thumbnails right)           Mobile View
+----------------------+-------------+       +----------------------+
| Section 1            | Section 2   |       | Section 1            | 
|                      |             |       |                      |
+----------------------+-------------+       +----------------------+
| Image Slider Section | Thumbnails  |       | Section 2            |
|                      | # # # # # # |       |                      |
|                      | # # # # # # |       +----------------------+
|                      | # # # # # # |       | Image Slider Section |
+----------------------+-------------+       |                      |
| Section 3            | Section 4   |       |                      |
|                      |             |       |                      |
|                      +-------------+       +----------------------+
|                      | Section 5   |       | Thumbnails           |
|                      |             |       |  # # # # # # # # # # |
+----------------------+-------------+       |  # # # # # # # # # # |
| Section 6                          |       +----------------------+
|                                    |       | Section 3            | 
+----------------------+-------------+       |                      |
                                             |                      |
  Large View (with thumbnails bottom)        |                      |
+----------------------+-------------+       |                      |
| Section 1            | Section 2   |       |                      |
|                      |             |       +----------------------+
+----------------------+-------------+       | Section 4            |
| Image Slider Section | Section 4   |       |                      |
|                      |             |       +----------------------+
|                      +-------------+       | Section 5            |
|                      | Section 5   |       |                      |
+----------------------+             |       +----------------------+
| Thumbnails           |-------------+       | Section 6            |
| # # # # # # # # # # #|                     |                      |
+----------------------+                     +----------------------+
| Section 3            |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
+----------------------+-------------+
| Section 6                          |
|                                    |
+----------------------+-------------+

Both large views are valuable options.
```

I've been told that I should structure and order my cols with mobile-first in mind. That's the HTML:

```
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col s12 m8">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Share Buttons Section</h5>
      </section>

      <!--<section class="col s12 m4">-->
      <!--<h5 class="teal-text">Nothing (Just a Placeholder)</h5>-->
      <!--</section>-->


      <section class="col s12 m8">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 1</h5>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m4">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 2</h5>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m8">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Pushpin Nav</h5>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m8">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Slider Section</h5>
        <div class="col s2 amber" style="margin: 3px; width: 100%; height: 480px"></div>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m8">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Slider Thumbnails</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <!--...-->
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m8">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 3</h5>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>Section 4</h5>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>Section 5</h5>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12">
        <h5>Section 6</h5>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

This leaves some gaps in between the sections in the large view if the content of a section is bigger than the other remaining for this row.
Ok cool, so I came across [push / pull](http://materializecss.com/grid.html#grid-push), which I thought would reorder the columns, and fix the problem if I just push and pull them into the right order. But that causes just to "re-order" the offset in the horizontal space. Gaps still there.

What am I missing, to get the content stick together?

I really appreciate a detailed answer providing some examples, so I understand this kind of issue.

Link to my jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/

Comment: Slider Thumbnails Section for the (large view with thumbnails to the right would be) `<section class="col s12 m4">` instead. Same order. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/1/

Comment: Maybe use bootstrap 4. It allows you to do it out of the box, check out the link here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns

Comment: First I've to say thanks for your comment @Syfer . But, I don't think it's the typical masonry-like behavior for cards (with random content) which i'm looking for. Materializecss offers a preview implementation of this as well, by looking for the `.col`s and rearrange them: http://materializecss.com/templates/masonry-template/preview.html  
It's definitely something which goes some kind in the direction of what I want to accomplish but based on the layout. (in a more static way). I tried it on the example i'd provided, but this has some ugly side effects. https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/6/

Comment: Ok sorry, the ugly side effects, was caused by the `.col`s I'd used for thumbnail images which also had the class `.col` on the elements. Fixing this https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/7/ but this just do not align the `.m4` columns correctly, they are used like `.s12` sized columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

You can achieve the mentioned grid layout via `flex` CSS property.

> for more info on CSS `flex` you read [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

If you care about cross-compatiblity with older browsers as you should, `display:flex;` alone is not recommended. You need to add those `old flexbox prefixes`. As `for IE8 and 9`, you can use a `table fallback`. Which comes to the following rule set:

```
.flex-container {
  display: table;        /* IE < 10, Opera *Presto* Desktop (Now dead) */
  display: -webkit-box;  /* Safari 3.1 - 6, Chrome < 21 (2009 Spec), UCBrowser Android */
  display: -moz-box;     /* Firefox 2 - 27 (2009 Spec), UCMini Android */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* IE10 (2012 Syntax) */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari 6.1 - 8, Android < 4.4, BB < 10, Chrome 21 - 28 */
  display: flex;         /* Edge 12+, Firefox 28+, Blink, Safari 9+, Opera Mini 8+ */
}
```

For the `flex items` `table-cell` or `table-row` fallbacks, especially with flexbox nesting.

However, there are 3 options available:

1) Use feature detection with a script like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs). And use the Modernizr CSS document styling to declare the IE8-9 fallback rules via JS feature detection. Like this:

```
html.no-flexbox .flex-item {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

2) Use IE CSS conditional styling:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-8-9-fallbacks.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

OR

3) The other no-JS way is using CSS hacks. With a display value which will ignored by other browsers, and only be parsed and applied by IE8-9.

With: a)

```
.flex-item {
  display: block;
  display: table-cell\0/; /*IE8-10 */
}
```

and/or: b)

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 { /* IE6-10 and exclude FF2 */
  .flex-item { display: table-cell; }
}
```

Demo for `Large View (with thumbnails right)` **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/3/)**

Demo for `Large View (with thumbnails bottom)` **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkdzgafr/5/)**

CSS:

```
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .d-flex {
    display: flex;
  }
  .h-100p {
    height: 100%
  }
  .h-50p {
    height: 50%;
  }
  .mb-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML:** **( Large View - with thumbnails right )**

```
<article class="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col s12 m8 amber lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Share Buttons Section</h5>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!--<section class="col s12 m4 red lighten-5">-->
    <!--<h5 class="teal-text">Nothing (Just a Placeholder)</h5>-->
    <!--</section>-->

    <div class="row d-flex">
      <section class="col s12 m8 blue lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 1</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto cum cumque deserunt dignissimos error esse expedita illum, magni nobis odit optio quas, quisquam recusandae sequi soluta tempore, vel voluptas voluptatibus.
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m4 red lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 2</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, pariatur?<br> Lorem: <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col s12 m8 amber lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Pushpin Nav</h5>
        <p class="light center">
          <a>Lorem-section</a> - <a>ipsum-section</a> - <a>dolor-section</a> - <a>sit-section</a>
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex">
      <section class="col s12 m8 blue lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Slider Section</h5>
        <div class="col s2 amber" style="margin: 3px; width: 100%; height: 480px"></div>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m4 red lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Slider Thumbnails</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex">
      <div class="col s12 m8">
        <div class="row mb-0">
          <section class="col s12 blue lighten-5">
            <h5 class="teal-text">Section 3</h5>
            <p class="light justify">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis officia quaerat quisquam. Animi beatae excepturi explicabo iste libero modi quae quam. Aliquid placeat similique voluptatum? Atque debitis dolores ex fuga fugit nam natus temporibus ullam
              unde. Adipisci alias aliquid aperiam aspernatur atque aut autem blanditiis distinctio, doloribus ea fuga illum inventore laudantium minus mollitia nulla officia praesentium, quidem soluta tempora, unde vel veniam. Aperiam, corporis dignissimos,
              eveniet fugiat iure neque nobis provident quas rem repellat, sit tempore ut. Assumenda aut nesciunt nihil voluptates. Ad aliquid, animi atque aut culpa debitis dolorem doloribus eaque et facere fugiat impedit in incidunt ipsa labore laborum
              natus nesciunt nisi nulla officiis perspiciatis quasi quidem quisquam quod rem rerum sint sit suscipit tenetur totam ullam vero vitae voluptas. Accusamus aliquid amet commodi dolore dolores error et hic ipsa iusto nihil nisi nobis provident
              quas quibusdam ratione saepe soluta, suscipit? Ab, asperiores autem commodi consectetur culpa cumque deleniti dolorem, doloremque eaque earum eligendi eveniet, ex expedita facere illum laudantium maxime modi neque non nulla obcaecati odio
              optio quia quisquam quod sint sunt totam unde voluptas voluptatibus. Ad aliquam architecto aspernatur assumenda commodi culpa debitis deleniti doloremque eos esse exercitationem incidunt ipsam iste laborum magnam, magni maiores molestias
              necessitatibus neque nesciunt nobis nostrum, omnis possimus provident quaerat qui quod reprehenderit sapiente temporibus totam ullam veritatis vitae voluptatum. Ab animi, delectus ducimus excepturi facilis ipsam natus nulla optio pariatur
              quod repellendus sed, similique suscipit tenetur totam! Accusantium dolor iste iure magnam modi omnis possimus, quod voluptate!Itaque, unde?
            </p>
            <p class="light justify">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis officia quaerat quisquam. Animi beatae excepturi explicabo iste libero modi quae quam. Aliquid placeat similique voluptatum? Atque debitis dolores ex fuga fugit nam natus temporibus ullam
              unde. Adipisci alias aliquid aperiam aspernatur atque aut autem blanditiis distinctio, doloribus ea fuga illum inventore laudantium minus mollitia nulla officia praesentium, quidem soluta tempora, unde vel veniam. Aperiam, corporis dignissimos,
              eveniet fugiat iure neque nobis provident quas rem repellat, sit tempore ut. Assumenda aut nesciunt nihil voluptates. Ad aliquid, animi atque aut culpa debitis dolorem doloribus eaque et facere fugiat impedit in incidunt ipsa labore laborum
              natus nesciunt nisi nulla officiis perspiciatis quasi quidem quisquam quod rem rerum sint sit suscipit tenetur totam ullam vero vitae voluptas. Accusamus aliquid amet commodi dolore dolores error et hic ipsa iusto nihil nisi nobis provident
              quas quibusdam ratione saepe soluta, suscipit? Ab, asperiores autem commodi consectetur culpa cumque deleniti dolorem, doloremque eaque earum eligendi eveniet, ex expedita facere illum laudantium maxime modi neque non nulla obcaecati odio
              optio quia quisquam quod sint sunt totam unde voluptas voluptatibus. Ad aliquam architecto aspernatur assumenda commodi culpa debitis deleniti doloremque eos esse exercitationem incidunt ipsam iste laborum magnam, magni maiores molestias
              necessitatibus neque nesciunt nobis nostrum, omnis possimus provident quaerat qui quod reprehenderit sapiente temporibus totam ullam veritatis vitae voluptatum. Ab animi, delectus ducimus excepturi facilis ipsam natus nulla optio pariatur
              quod repellendus sed, similique suscipit tenetur totam! Accusantium dolor iste iure magnam modi omnis possimus, quod voluptate! Itaque, unde?
            </p>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="row h-100p">

          <section class="col s12  red lighten-5 h-50p">
            <h5 class="teal-text">Section 4</h5>
            <p class="light justify">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam consequuntur cupiditate vero?
            </p>
          </section>

          <section class="col s12  red lighten-5 h-50p">
            <h5 class="teal-text">Section 5</h5>
            <p class="light justify">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, pariatur?<br> Lorem: <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            </p>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <section class="col s12 green lighten-5">
      <h5 class="teal-text">Section 6</h5>
      <p class="light justify">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque deserunt ipsa qui quisquam sunt velit. Amet aperiam architecto delectus deserunt, ducimus eos ipsam magni omnis, placeat provident qui quibusdam.
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>

</article>
```

**HTML:** **( Large View (with thumbnails bottom) )**

```
<article class="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col s12 m8 amber lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Share Buttons Section</h5> 
      </section>
    </div>
      <!--<section class="col s12 m4 red lighten-5">-->
      <!--<h5 class="teal-text">Nothing (Just a Placeholder)</h5>-->
      <!--</section>-->

<div class="row d-flex">
      <section class="col s12 m8 blue lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 1</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto cum cumque deserunt dignissimos error esse expedita illum, magni nobis odit optio quas, quisquam recusandae sequi soluta tempore, vel voluptas voluptatibus.
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 m4 red lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 2</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, pariatur?<br> Lorem: <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
        </p>
      </section>
</div>
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col s12 m8 amber lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Pushpin Nav</h5>
        <p class="light center">
          <a>Lorem-section</a> - <a>ipsum-section</a> - <a>dolor-section</a> - <a>sit-section</a>
        </p>
      </section>
      </div>
<div class="row d-flex">
<div class="col s12 m8">
<div class="row mb-0">
      <section class="col s12 blue lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Slider Section</h5>
        <div class="col s2 amber" style="margin: 3px; width: 100%; height: 480px"></div>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12 red lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Slider Thumbnails</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div> 
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div> 
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
          <div class="col s2 blue" style="margin: 3px; width: 48px; height: 48px"></div>
        </div>
      </section>

        <section class="col s12 blue lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 3</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis officia quaerat quisquam. Animi beatae excepturi explicabo iste libero modi quae quam. Aliquid placeat similique voluptatum? Atque debitis dolores ex fuga fugit nam natus temporibus ullam
          unde. Adipisci alias aliquid aperiam aspernatur atque aut autem blanditiis distinctio, doloribus ea fuga illum inventore laudantium minus mollitia nulla officia praesentium, quidem soluta tempora, unde vel veniam. Aperiam, corporis dignissimos,
          eveniet fugiat iure neque nobis provident quas rem repellat, sit tempore ut. Assumenda aut nesciunt nihil voluptates. Ad aliquid, animi atque aut culpa debitis dolorem doloribus eaque et facere fugiat impedit in incidunt ipsa labore laborum
          natus nesciunt nisi nulla officiis perspiciatis quasi quidem quisquam quod rem rerum sint sit suscipit tenetur totam ullam vero vitae voluptas. Accusamus aliquid amet commodi dolore dolores error et hic ipsa iusto nihil nisi nobis provident
          quas quibusdam ratione saepe soluta, suscipit? Ab, asperiores autem commodi consectetur culpa cumque deleniti dolorem, doloremque eaque earum eligendi eveniet, ex expedita facere illum laudantium maxime modi neque non nulla obcaecati odio optio
          quia quisquam quod sint sunt totam unde voluptas voluptatibus. Ad aliquam architecto aspernatur assumenda commodi culpa debitis deleniti doloremque eos esse exercitationem incidunt ipsam iste laborum magnam, magni maiores molestias necessitatibus
          neque nesciunt nobis nostrum, omnis possimus provident quaerat qui quod reprehenderit sapiente temporibus totam ullam veritatis vitae voluptatum. Ab animi, delectus ducimus excepturi facilis ipsam natus nulla optio pariatur quod repellendus
          sed, similique suscipit tenetur totam! Accusantium dolor iste iure magnam modi omnis possimus, quod voluptate!Itaque, unde?
        </p>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis officia quaerat quisquam. Animi beatae excepturi explicabo iste libero modi quae quam. Aliquid placeat similique voluptatum? Atque debitis dolores ex fuga fugit nam natus temporibus ullam
          unde. Adipisci alias aliquid aperiam aspernatur atque aut autem blanditiis distinctio, doloribus ea fuga illum inventore laudantium minus mollitia nulla officia praesentium, quidem soluta tempora, unde vel veniam. Aperiam, corporis dignissimos,
          eveniet fugiat iure neque nobis provident quas rem repellat, sit tempore ut. Assumenda aut nesciunt nihil voluptates. Ad aliquid, animi atque aut culpa debitis dolorem doloribus eaque et facere fugiat impedit in incidunt ipsa labore laborum
          natus nesciunt nisi nulla officiis perspiciatis quasi quidem quisquam quod rem rerum sint sit suscipit tenetur totam ullam vero vitae voluptas. Accusamus aliquid amet commodi dolore dolores error et hic ipsa iusto nihil nisi nobis provident
          quas quibusdam ratione saepe soluta, suscipit? Ab, asperiores autem commodi consectetur culpa cumque deleniti dolorem, doloremque eaque earum eligendi eveniet, ex expedita facere illum laudantium maxime modi neque non nulla obcaecati odio optio
          quia quisquam quod sint sunt totam unde voluptas voluptatibus. Ad aliquam architecto aspernatur assumenda commodi culpa debitis deleniti doloremque eos esse exercitationem incidunt ipsam iste laborum magnam, magni maiores moles
          tias necessitatibus
          neque nesciunt nobis nostrum, omnis possimus provident quaerat qui quod reprehenderit sapiente temporibus totam ullam veritatis vitae voluptatum. Ab animi, delectus ducimus excepturi facilis ipsam natus nulla optio pariatur quod repellendus
          sed, similique suscipit tenetur totam! Accusantium dolor iste iure magnam modi omnis possimus, quod voluptate! Itaque, unde?
        </p>
      </section>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col s12 m4">
       <div class="row h-100p">
          <section class="col s12 h-50p  red lighten-5 h-50p">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 4</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam consequuntur cupiditate vero?
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="col s12  red lighten-5 h-50p">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 5</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, pariatur?<br> Lorem: <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
        </p>
      </section>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>  

      <section class="col s12 h-50p green lighten-5">
        <h5 class="teal-text">Section 6</h5>
        <p class="light justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque deserunt ipsa qui quisquam sunt velit. Amet aperiam architecto delectus deserunt, ducimus eos ipsam magni omnis, placeat provident qui quibusdam.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>

</article>
```

Comment: `display: flex` seems to be pretty cool. As I can see you just put `display: flex;`on every `.row`-div on which the remaining div's should "flex" around? _(Which was Section 1 & (Slider Section or Section 3))_

Comment: But wait, flex is a quite new browser-feature (like grid https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/ which is even newer), which would lack browser support on older browser?! Is there an alternative implementation maybe?

Comment: @MrMAG The `flexbox` supported by IE10+ and all the major browsers. For more info on flexbox support visit [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex). As since there are `fallbacks available` for flexbox available for `ancient browsers` too.  For IE8 and 9, you can use a table fallback indeed targeting IE8 desktop  browser. I Will update my answer with available fallbacks  for old browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This answer answers pretty much what I were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Space is because of `float:left` for the section. Try placing the Section 2 with `float:right` which will solve your problem.

> About float: it is taken out of the normal flow of the document
>   (though still remaining part of it). It is shifted to the left, or
>   right until it touches the edge of its containing box, or another
>   floated element.

The next float element is placed when the previous row left floated element height completes.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use the `display: flex` property which is currently, as of the 8th June, supported by more browsers than the `display: grid` property. If you'd like to test it without having to enable it, simply install Chrome BETA at [chrome.com/beta](http://www.chrome.com/beta).